# Bring up/back the location permission dialog?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Because my website requires the users' locations, they need to allow access to it. The user can deny access once, and/or perhaps save the preference of deny for the website.  But what if at a later time the user decides to give the website his/her location and for whatever reason the permission dialog does not come up by itself?

Is there a way to bring up the permission dialog or perhaps create your dialog/alert that functions the same as the permissions dialog using javascript/dojo?

Answer (score 0):

I think such preferences need to be stored as a persistent data, in database at server side or a cookie on the user's machine. So everytime user logs into your website, this data(from database or cookie) should be crosschecked and if they had previously decided not to allow such access, the permissions dialog should be popped. (Is  this the answer you are looking for?)

Comment: no this is not what I was asking.  Let's say the user decides to deny permissions at first when the dialog comes up and the user saves that preference for the whole website so the dialog never comes up again.  Then at some point in the future, the user decides to WANT to give me access to his/her location.  This requires him/her to click allow in the permissions dialog.  However, since the user's preference is saved to the browser, the dialog never automatically comes up again for the user to click allow.  How can I  manually bring the permissions dialog back with javascript/dojo?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force the authorization dialog to popup. This is a native implementation of a security component and will remember the users choice until the day his pc dies - or the preferences are purged. CTRL+SHIFT+DEL comes into mind and a quick test tells me for FF11+ at least, the flag you should inform users to select is 'Site Preferences'